# How to simulate OptimisticConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wanted to make OptimisticConcurrencyException in EF by following code; But it does not cause the exception!

```
   int device101 = SqlAggregateTestData.DeviceId101;
        IfaEntities context1 = new IfaEntities();
        IfaEntities context2 = new IfaEntities();


        var device1 = context1.Devices.Find(device101);
        context1.Entry(device1).State=EntityState.Modified;
        device1.Name = "sss";

        var device2 = context2.Devices.Find(device101);
        context2.Entry(device2).State=EntityState.Modified;
        device2.Name = "ss22222s";

        context2.SaveChanges();
        context1.SaveChanges();
```

I want this to test my EF code base against OptimisticConcurrencyException.

Comment: Why not simply `throw new OptimisticConcurrencyException()`? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Christian.K  my DbContext sometimes throws OptimisticConcurrencyException in deployment server, and i can't find why is that. So i need to know when and in which conditions this exception occurs?

Comment: What's the `State=EntityState.Modified` good for?`Remove it. It might cause something. Also, did you enable optimistic concurrency? Can you see it in SQL Profiler.

Comment: @usr, I'm trying to cause OptimisticConcurrencyException manually. as i said my dbcontext save method throw the exeption sometimes so it is enabled.

Comment: You just repeated statements you already made. I understand you goal. Why are you modifying the entity state? Remove it an retest.

Comment: @usr, I've removed those lines, and still the exception doesn't thrown.

Comment: Update the code please. `Also, did you enable optimistic concurrency? Can you see it in SQL Profiler.`